# How to deallocate an acces type variable before returning value at end of function?

Tags: vhdl

In a function it would be convenient to use a `sting` `access` `type`, for example through `textio.line`, and the final value is the output from the function.  Simple example code that shows the issue, but not the motivation for using an `access` `type`:

```
function fun return string is
  variable line_v : line;
begin
  line_v := new string'("Hello VHDL world");
  return line_v.all;  -- line_v is missing deallocate(line_v)
end function;
```

But this code is missing a `deallocate(line_v)` in order to avoid a memory leak when the allocated memory for the strings is not released.

How to make a `deallocate(line_v)`, when returning the value from `line_v`?

Comment: In this example you don't need the access type at all : initialise an unconstrained  **string** variable in its declaration and return that.

Comment: Agree; I simplified (removed) the actual string manipulations, so it is not obvious that using an `access` `type` is an advantage, but the background is that the intermediate and the result will be strings of different length, and for this the `access` `type` `string` (´line´) is a good choice.

Comment: Sometimes you can restructure the string manipulation this way; either via a series of function calls, each using the above, or as a slice of a fixed length string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now this is real ugly.

Start by creating a protected type:

```
package TextExtPkg is
  type LinePType is protected 
    procedure copy ( S : in  string ) ;
    impure function get ( EraseLine : boolean := TRUE) return string ;
  end protected LinePType ;
...
end TextExtPkg ;
package body TextExtPkg is 
  type LinePType is protected body
    variable Message : line ;
    procedure copy ( S : in  string ) is 
    begin
      deallocate(Message) ; 
      Message := new string'(S) ; 
    end procedure copy ;
    impure function get ( EraseLine : boolean := TRUE) return string is 
      variable value : string(1 to Message'length) ; 
    begin
      value := Message.all ; 
      if EraseLine then
        deallocate(Message) ; 
      end if ; 
      return value ; 
    end function get ;
  end protected body LinePType ;
end TextExtPkg ;
```

Then you put the value into the protected type, deallocate your local pointer, then get and return the value from the protected type.   It is not pretty, but it works.

```
function fun return string is
  variable line_v : line;
  variable PT : LinePType ; 
begin
  line_v := new string'("Hello VHDL world");
  PT.copy(line_v.all) ;  
  deallocate(line_v) ; 
  return PT.get(EraseLine => TRUE) ; 
end function;
```

I used mine to create a write and to_string (here named to_s) for integer_vector:

```
  procedure write (
    L          : inout line; 
    value      : in integer_vector;
    justified  : in side := RIGHT; 
    field      : in width := 0
  ) is
  begin
    for i in value'range loop 
      write(L, value(i), justified, field) ; 
      if i /= value'right then
        write(L, ' ') ;  -- delimiter
      end if ; 
    end loop ;
  end procedure write ; 

  impure function to_s (
    value      : in integer_vector;
    justified  : in side := RIGHT; 
    field      : in width := 0
  ) return string is
    variable L : line; 
    variable PT : LinePType ; 
  begin
    write(L, value, justified, field) ;    
    if L = NULL then return  "" ; end if ; 
    PT.copy(L.all) ;  
    deallocate(L) ; 
    return PT.get(EraseLine => TRUE) ; 
  end function to_s ;
```

You can find the whole package at:  http://synthworks.com/TextExtPkg.vhd

Comment: Thanks Jim.  Though the solution requires more writing up front, use of the protected type (PT) is pretty small when applied, code only executes once, and the user is not exposed to artifacts, so the solution encapsulates problem.

Comment: I should add that in VHDL-2017, there will be more elegant ways to address this.

Answer (score 2):

Deallocating the object denoted by the line_v Line access type requires first assigning it's value to a dynamically elaborated object for use as a return value following deallocation.

The difficulty in doing this comes from the requirement that the dynamically declared object's declaration must be static at elaboration time meaning the subtype of the object must be known.

In some programming languages this is possible by the use of in line declarations where once the length of say a character array is known the value of an allocated area of memory can be copied to a newly declared.

VHDL does not have that capability. There is a way however to emulate it with a nested function call:

```
entity noleak is
end entity;

architecture fum of noleak is
    impure function fun return string is
        use std.textio.all;
        variable line_v : line;
        impure function snip return string is
            variable retstr: string (1 to line_v'length);
        begin
            retstr := line_v.all;
            deallocate (line_v);
            return retstr;
        end function;
    begin
        line_v := new string'("Hello VHDL world!");
         return snip;
    end function;
begin
    process
    begin
        report "fun return = " & fun;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The function snip is impure because it modifies the line_v access object.

The function fun is impure because it's the parent of an impure function (snip).

The function snip is declared an contains a return string variable who's length is dependent on the value of the length of the string value pointed to by the access object line_v.

Why this can work is because a declarative item in a subprogram declaration can be another subprogram specification. Doing so provides direct visibility to preceding declarations (line_v in this case).

The length of the object accessed by line_v is used in a dynamically elaborated function call to define the subtype of retstr (it's length).

In the body of snip the value of object accessed by line_v is copied to the dynamically elaborated retstr and line_v is deallocated. This represents conversion of the allocated object (a heap variable) to a dynamically elaborated object (a stack variable) followed by freeing the allocated object.

This is as close as you can get in VHDL to doing in line declarations.

The idea here is to prevent memory leaks in VHDL implementations that do not do garbage collection which could deallocate storage automatically here if the access type value is not returned from a function or is not a  parameter of mode out or inout for a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to return the access type instead of the string:

```
library IEEE;
use std.textio.all;

  function fun return line is
    variable line_v : line;
  begin
    line_v := new string'("Hello VHDL world");
    return line_v;
  end function;
```

And then to deallocate outside the function:

```
library IEEE;
use std.textio.all;

entity E is
end entity E;

architecture E of E is
  function fun return line is
    variable line_v : line;
  begin
    line_v := new string'("Hello VHDL world");
    return line_v;
  end function;
begin

  process
    variable L : line := fun;
  begin
    report L.all;
    deallocate(L);
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture E;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3kCu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and it may be useful in some cases.  Though it would be nice to avoid that the user function should clean up and intermediate from the function.

Answer (score 1):

How would you do this deallocate in a C function call?

VHDL doesn't allow in line declarations, meaning the only way to deallocate the storage in the function is to have a dynamically declared object value you return. That would entail using a maximum length return value that can be guarded:

```
entity noleak is
end entity;

architecture fum of noleak is
    function fun (maxlen: natural := 16) return string is
        use std.textio.all;
        variable line_v : line;
        variable retstr:  string (1 to maxlen);
        variable len:     natural;
    begin
        line_v := new string'("Hello VHDL world!");
        len := line_v.all'length;
        if len <= maxlen then
            retstr(1 to len) := line_v.all;
            deallocate(line_v);
            return retstr(1 to len);
        end if;
        deallocate(line_v);
        return fun(maxlen => len);
    end function;
begin
    process
    begin
        report "fun return = " & fun(maxlen => 17);
        report "fun return = " & fun;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Which returns:

```
ghdl -r noleak
leak.vhdl:87:9:@0ms:(report note): fun return = Hello VHDL world!
leak.vhdl:88:9:@0ms:(report note): fun return = Hello VHDL world!
```

The guard is incorporated as the length of a string array dynamically elaborated (it's a stack variable).

If the string denoted by the Line access variable is longer than that string arrary variable the function is recursively called with the correct length.  (Noting the function hasn't been declared as impure.)

You pick the maxlen default value based on what you think will work in one pass. If you were wrong it'll correct it by recursion.

If you know it'll be wrong you pass a better estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  So basically this solution executes twice; 1st to find the length (if guess was too short) and 2nd to make the string and return it.

Comment: It'll only execute twice if line_v.all'length is longer than maxlen.  You could provide any default and if it's maxlen or shorter it will do one pass. You can also use a different default value for maxlen oat analysis time or pass it as a parameter to boost the range if you expect something bigger.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your point.  Thanks for commenting on this.